# Calculation of num of rects in a file

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

I am trying to use MPI c/c++ and OpenMP c/c++ Libraries to calculate how many rectangles in a given dataset.
the data set is a text file of 1s and 0s, it is very large like 100000x100000 lines of 0s and 1s, but for simplicity I will provide sample of the data in the set.

I initially though of putting the data into an integer 2d array, here how my dataset looks like

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

and I should get the coordinates of the 4 rectangles.

1. the one in top right (2 x 3 rectangle)
2. the one in left (3x3rectangle)
3. the 2 overlapping rectangles

the coordinates of each rectangle needed are: top-left corner & bottom-right corner

How can I approach this problem baring in mind the use of mpi/openmp libraries to make it efficient, do I need to divide the matrix on threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following would do the job.
Note that this (new, see history) algorithm should scale O(N), if I am not wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

//--some helper functions and structs--
typedef struct Line_s {
    long x0;
    long nx;
    long y0;
} Line;

typedef struct LineVect_s {
  Line *lines;
  long size;
  long capacity;
} LineVect;

LineVect* newLineVect(void) {
    LineVect *vect = malloc(sizeof(LineVect));
    vect->lines = malloc(sizeof(Line));
    vect->size = 0;
    vect->capacity = 1;
    return vect;
}

void deleteLineVect(LineVect* self) {
    free(self->lines);
    free(self);
}

void LineVect_pushBack(LineVect* self, Line line) {
    self->size++;
    if (self->size > self->capacity) {
        self->capacity *= 2;
        self->lines = realloc(self->lines, self->capacity * sizeof(Line));
    }
    self->lines[self->size - 1] = line;
}

typedef struct Block_s {
    long x0, y0;
    long nx, ny;
    char val;
} Block;

typedef struct BlockVect_s {
   Block *blocks;
   long size;
   long capacity;
} BlockVect;

BlockVect* newBlockVect(void) {
    BlockVect *vect = malloc(sizeof(BlockVect));
    vect->blocks = malloc(sizeof(Block));
    vect->size = 0;
    vect->capacity = 1;
    return vect;
}

void deleteBlockVect(BlockVect* self) {
    free(self->blocks);
    free(self);
}

void BlockVect_pushBack(BlockVect* self, Block block) {
    self->size++;
    if (self->size > self->capacity) {
        self->capacity *= 2;
        self->blocks = realloc(self->blocks, self->capacity * sizeof(Block));
    }
    self->blocks[self->size - 1] = block;
}


LineVect** find_lines(char* data, long nx, long ny) {
    LineVect **slices = malloc(ny * sizeof(LineVect*));
    //essentially each y-slice is independent here
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (long y = 0; y < ny; y++) {
        slices[y] = newLineVect();
        char prev_val = 0;
        long xstart = 0;
        for (long x = 0; x < nx; x++) {
            char val = data[nx*y + x];
            if (val == 1 && prev_val == 0) {
                xstart = x;
            } else if (val == 0 && prev_val == 1) {
                Line line;
                line.y0 = -1;
                line.x0 = xstart;
                line.nx = x - xstart;
//              printf("Found line at y=%d from x=%d to %d\n", y, xstart, x-1); 
                LineVect_pushBack(slices[y], line);
            }
            
            if (val == 1 && x == nx-1) {
                Line line;
                line.y0 = -1;
                line.x0 = xstart;
                line.nx = x - xstart + 1;
//              printf("Found line at y=%d from x=%d to %d\n", y, xstart, x);
                LineVect_pushBack(slices[y], line);
            }
            prev_val = val;
        }
    }
    return slices;
}

BlockVect* find_blocks(LineVect** slices, long ny) {
    BlockVect* blocks = newBlockVect();
    //for each line
    for (long y = 0; y < ny; y++) {
        LineVect* slice = slices[y];
        long l2 = 0;
        for (long l = 0; l < slice->size; l++) {
            Line *line = slice->lines + l;
            if (line->y0 == -1) {
                line->y0 = y;
            }
            char match = 0;
            //check next slice if there is any
            if (y != ny-1) {
                //check all the remaining lines in the next slice
                if (l2 < slices[y+1]->size) {
                    Line *line2 = slices[y+1]->lines + l2;
                    //note that we exploit the sorted nature of the lines (x0 must increase with l2)
                    for (; l2 < slices[y+1]->size && line2->x0 < line->x0; l2++) {
                        line2 = slices[y+1]->lines + l2;
                    }
                    //matching line2 found -> mark it as same block (y0 cascades)
                    if (line->x0 == line2->x0 && line->nx == line2->nx) {
                        match = 1;
                        line2->y0 = line->y0;
                    }
                }
            }
            //current line didn't find a matching line hence store it (and all the previously collected lines) as a block
            if (match == 0) {
                Block block;
                block.x0 = line->x0;
                block.nx = line->nx;
                block.y0 = line->y0;
                block.ny = y - line->y0 + 1;
                BlockVect_pushBack(blocks, block);
            }
        }
    }
    return blocks;
}

#define Nx 30000
#define Ny 30000

char * write_blocks(const BlockVect* blocks) {
    char * data = calloc(Ny, Nx*sizeof(char));
    for (long i = 0; i < blocks->size; i++) {
        Block *block = blocks->blocks + i;
        for (long y = block->y0; y < block->y0 + block->ny; y++) {
            for (long x = block->x0; x < block->x0 + block->nx; x++) {
                data[Nx*y + x] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}

int main() {
    struct timeval t0;
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    
//  char data[Ny][Nx] = {
//      {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
//      {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
//      {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
//      {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
//      {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
//      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
//      {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
//      {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
//  };
    
    srand(t0.tv_usec);
    char * input = calloc(Ny, Nx*sizeof(char));
    printf("Filling...\n");
    for (long y = 0; y < Ny; y++) {
        for (long x = 0; x < Nx; x++) {
            input[Nx*y + x] = rand() % 10 != 0; //data[y][x];
        }
    }
    printf("Computing...\n");
    struct timeval t;
    struct timeval t_new;
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    
    LineVect** slices = find_lines(input, Nx, Ny);
    
    gettimeofday(&t_new, NULL);
    printf("Finding lines took %lu milliseconds\n", (t_new.tv_sec - t.tv_sec)*1000 + (t_new.tv_usec -t.tv_usec) / 1000);
    
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    
    BlockVect* blocks = find_blocks(slices, Ny);
    
    gettimeofday(&t_new, NULL);
    printf("Finding blocks took %lu milliseconds\n", (t_new.tv_sec - t.tv_sec)*1000 + (t_new.tv_usec -t.tv_usec) / 1000);
    
    long n_lines = 0;
    for (long y = 0; y < Ny; y++) {
        n_lines += slices[y]->size;
        deleteLineVect(slices[y]);
    }
    free(slices);
    
    printf("Done computation of %ld lines and %ld blocks\n", n_lines, blocks->size);
    
    char * output = write_blocks(blocks);
    deleteBlockVect(blocks);
    
    char pass = 1;
    for (long y = 0; y < Ny; y++) {
        for (long x = 0; x < Nx; x++) {
            if (input[Nx*y + x] != output[Nx*y + x]) {
                printf("ERROR at x=%ld and y=%ld!\n", x, y);
                pass = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Plausibility check %s\n", pass ? "PASSED" : "FAILED");
    
    //free all the rest
    free(input);
    free(output);
    gettimeofday(&t_new, NULL);
    printf("Whole run took %.3lf seconds\n", (t_new.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) + (t_new.tv_usec -t0.tv_usec) * 1e-6);
}
```

---

### Scaling tests:

---

#### On my laptop (Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4310U @ 2.0 GHz, 2 physical cores):

OMP_NUM_THREADS=1

```
Filling...
Computing...
Finding lines took 2973 milliseconds
Finding blocks took 2035 milliseconds
Done computation of 81012713 lines and 80743987 blocks
Plausibility check PASSED
Whole run took 16.981 seconds
```

OMP_NUM_THREADS=2

```
Filling...
Computing...
Finding lines took 1725 milliseconds
Finding blocks took 2019 milliseconds
Done computation of 81027281 lines and 80757086 blocks
Plausibility check PASSED
Whole run took 15.392 seconds
```

---

#### On my PC (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 4 physical cores):

OMP_NUM_THREADS=1

```
Filling...
Computing...
Finding lines took 3656 milliseconds
Finding blocks took 1631 milliseconds
Done computation of 81024019 lines and 80754472 blocks
Plausibility check PASSED
Whole run took 13.611 seconds
```

OMP_NUM_THREADS=4

```
Filling...
Computing...
Finding lines took 1007 milliseconds
Finding blocks took 1637 milliseconds
Done computation of 81036637 lines and 80766687 blocks
Plausibility check PASSED
Whole run took 11.055 seconds
```

OMP_NUM_THREADS=8

```
Filling...
Computing...
Finding lines took 812 milliseconds
Finding blocks took 1655 milliseconds
Done computation of 81025147 lines and 80754509 blocks
Plausibility check PASSED
Whole run took 11.137 seconds
```

So it seems, scaling of the parallel part (line finding) is quite good.
The most time of the run takes the actual generation of the sample data by random numbers (filling). Compared to that, the finding of the rects is quite quick.

Comment: If you really want to go for OpenMPI or similarly do a distributed memory approach with openmp I suggest the following: Decompose the domain into subdomains such that each thread/process runs the above code for its subdomain. Finally you would need some communication where only those blocks which touch the boundaries of the subdomains are exchanged within the thread/process team. However this requires plenty of code especially using MPI. Good luck though!

Comment: Hello, may I know what the _s stands for, I know that _t for POSIX is just a convention that means type, I guess _s means it is a structure right? I would like to email you to ask few questions about the code provided if you don't mind

Comment: @AbdullahAlSulaiman The _s is just to keep typedef and struct formally different, i.e. it can be omitted but it helps some IDEs to distinguish the typedef from the struct. I won't expose my mail address here, sry. You may ask all the questions here. I thought you wanted a public debate.

Comment: Alright, my question is how does the find_blocks algorithm work, from what I understood, you first try to find consecutive lines of 1s, then you pass it to the function find_blocks
but when I tried to understand the find_block it is a bit confusing how does it actually find if the passed line is indeed a block (means it is a rectangle)
I really appreciate your work on the code, I just wanted to understand every part of it so I can move on to implement the parallization of the code via MPI/OpenMP

Comment: Well, you can see a rectangle as a stack of lines which share same lengths and starting positions. This is what is checked for in the condition (line2.x0 == line.x0 && line2.nx == line.nx). Note that there can be only a single line for every y-coordinate to fulfill the criterion, hence the break afterwards. The implemented algorithm is however not very efficient, because for each line it searches within all the lines in the next slice. You might improve this a little and it might perform much better. I just didn't invest too much in making it perfect.

Comment: I included a new code in the answer, which should perform much faster and in addition is more readable. I hope you can follow the ideas. I highly suggest taking pen and paper for a proper understanding. How does it scale on your machine?